# Do I need a Mac Provisioning Profile (Distribution) when uploading my unity app to the Mac App Store

Tags: unity-game-engine, app-store-connect, provisioning-profile, mac-app-store, application-loader

I am submitting an app made in unity to the Mac app store currently, using application loader 3.0 to submit my build to iTunes connect. I was just wondering if in order to do this I am required to use/embed a Mac Provisioning Profile (Distribution) as I was told I had to but there is no mention of this in the unity docs concerning how to upload one's app to the mac app store. So my question would be if I would need to have a Mac Provisioning Profile (Distribution) and if so how would I implement it.

Comment: Yes, any app going in the Mac App Store needs to be signed with a distribution signing identity and a Distribution profile.   I haven't done so in Unity, so I'll leave that to someone with experience to answer.  But in the meantime, you'll want to generate the distribution profile /cert.

Comment: @wottle thank you, and yes I already have done so

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Assuming you have now created a .app, you must sign the .app package and all other binaries if your app relies on third party packages.

It will look like this:

codesign -f -s "3rd Party Mac Developer Application: YOUR NAME (TEAM ID)" --entitlements "entitlements.plist" "YourPackage.app"

And the same for other binaries inside the app.

Comment: something like this: codesign -f --deep -s '3rd Party Mac Developer Application: DEVELOPER NAME' --entitlements "GAMENAME.entitlements" "/AppPath/GAMENAME.app"?

Comment: Yes, but adding -deep can cause strange issues when it signs things that should not be signed. You will find out what they are when you upload via Application Loader.

Comment: Does not answer the question. The question was about whether or not to include a Mac Provisioning Profile (Distribution) along with the app or package. The answer is about signing the app using a signing identity, which is a whole different thing.

Answer (score 1):

No, you only require the app to be signed with the 3rd party developer certificate.

The provisioning file is only needed for local testing.

This is somewhat confusing because the same process for the iOS app store does require the inclusion of a distribution provisioning files.

Comment: Thankyou, but how I sign my app with a 3rd party developer certificate?

Comment: Sorry to resurrect, but how do I use a provisioning profile with Unity for local testing? I got the .app built. But when I build and sign a .pkg, I cannot install it locally